# how do you interpret the forecast in r, mainly Lo 80 Hi 80 lo 95 Hi 95?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, box-jenkins

```
        Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2017 Q1       230627.8 227619.2 233636.3 226026.6 235228.9
2017 Q2       230552.6 226719.9 234385.3 224691.0 236414.3
2017 Q3       236782.3 232580.2 240984.3 230355.8 243208.7
2017 Q4       242080.8 237454.1 246707.5 235004.8 249156.7
2018 Q1       243504.0 237544.7 249463.2 234390.1 252617.8
2018 Q2       244802.5 237948.5 251656.5 234320.2 255284.7
2018 Q3       250212.8 242778.2 257647.5 238842.6 261583.1
2018 Q4       254831.2 246703.1 262959.3 242400.4 267262.0

    massive <- ts(consumtion[,2], frequency=4, start=c(1990,01))
plot(massive,ylab='R Millions',xlab='Quarter', main='Final consumption expenditure by general government')

#Identification

library(forecast)
tsdisplay(diff(massive),main="First Difference Final consumption expenditure by general government")
tsdisplay(diff(diff(massive)),main="Second Difference Final consumption expenditure by general government")


acf(massive)
acf(diff(diff(massive)))
pacf(diff(diff(massive)))

#Competing models
#arima(3,1,0)
#arima(2,1,0)
#arima(1,1,0)

#auto.arima
library(forecast)
ARIMAfit<-auto.arima(massive)
ARIMAfit


#Estimation
fit <- Arima(massive, order=c(0,2,1))
summary(fit)
fit1 <- Arima(massive, order=c(0,2,2))
summary(fit1)
fit2 <- Arima(massive, order=c(0,2,3))
summary(fit2)
fit3 <- Arima(massive, order=c(1,2,0))
summary(fit3)
fit4 <- Arima(massive, order=c(1,2,1))
summary(fit4)
fit5 <- Arima(massive, order=c(1,2,2))
summary(fit5)
fit6 <- Arima(massive, order=c(1,2,3))
summary(fit6)
fit7 <- Arima(massive, order=c(2,2,0))
summary(fit7)
fit8 <- Arima(massive, order=c(2,2,1))
summary(fit8)
fit9 <- Arima(massive, order=c(2,2,2))
summary(fit9)
fit10 <- Arima(massive, order=c(2,2,3))
summary(fit10)
fit11 <- Arima(massive, order=c(3,2,0))
summary(fit11)
fit12 <- Arima(massive, order=c(3,2,1))
summary(fit12)
fit13 <- Arima(massive, order=c(3,2,2))
summary(fit13)
fit14 <- Arima(massive, order=c(3,2,3))
summary(fit14)
fit15 <- Arima(massive, order=c(4,2,0))
summary(fit15)
fit16 <- Arima(massive, order=c(4,2,1))
summary(fit16)
fit17 <- Arima(massive, order=c(4,2,2))
summary(fit17)
fit18 <- Arima(massive, order=c(4,2,3))
summary(fit18)

#Best Model is ARIMA(3,1,0)
#Diagnostic Checking
Acf(residuals(fit16))
Box.test(residuals(fit16), lag=24, fitdf=4, type="Ljung")

#Forecasting

plot(forecast(fit16))
forecast(fit16)
```

Comment: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/top-ten-list-of-reasons-to-close-a-question-immediately/4554#4554 makes a general point that "how to interpret" questions based on a copy of output are inherently unclear. Editing your question to make more precise what you do and do not understand may help.

Answer (score 3):

I cant quite decipher what is going on from the code you have posted but I believe the lo80 and hi80 would represent the lower and upper bounds respectively of some 80% interval.

If this were an 80% confidence interval then you would interpret this as meaning you are 80% confident that the true population forecast is somewhere between your lo80 value and your hi80 value. The lo95 and hi95 would then be the same thing but for 95%CIs.

Edit: as Whuber pointed out below, given this is dealing with forecasted values this would actually be a case of a prediction interval rather than a confidence interval. For a prediction interval, the interval represents the range of plausible values we expect to observe at some  future point in time. An 80% prediction interval is often interpreted as telling us that there is an 80% probability that the future observation's value will fall somewhere between the lower and upper bounds. More specifically, an 80% prediction interval is telling us that if we calculated 80% prediction intervals across repeated samples, then the future observation's value should fall within the lower and upper bounds on approx. 80% of these samples.

Comment: Forecasts are intervals for *random variables* and therefore do not fit within the concept of confidence intervals, which concern *parameters*.  You probably mean to refer to *prediction intervals* rather than CIs.

Comment: Thank you for the correction whuber. I've edited the answer accordingly. I don't deal with predictions much so I welcome edits to my explanation of the prediction interval

Comment: +1 This is a good description of a (frequentist) prediction interval.  Thanks for adding it.

Comment: Good point. From a cursory look at the code posted I'm pretty sure these represent frequentist prediction intervals.